# Aware of img tags with empty src in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome

As I figured out, Chrome do not ignore empty src, but loading currently viewed file into it. I had statistics counting error because of this "feature".

Create file.php with this code...

```
<?
  $fp = fopen("log", "a+");
  fwrite($fp, time()."\");
  fclose($fp);
?>
<h1>Here is my page...</h1>
<img src="" />
<img src="" />
```

..and try loading in Firefox and Chrome. On Chrome one visit to file.php will generate 3 lines in log instead of one. But everything is ok in FF, IE.

Is it bug or feature? My opinion - bug.

Hope it will help anybody!

Comment: very weird, and if you add more than 2 images chrome still makes 3 requests in total. i also noticed for the first time that it doesn't display the "alt" text if provided :(

Answer (score 1):

See this Chromium bug report: http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=38144